# SQL plus statement to a JAVA query

Tags: sql

I am trying to execute:

```
SELECT P_NUMBER FROM RDIMARS;
```

In another part of my code, I can successfully execute this statement:

```
ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery("SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM USER_TABLES " +
" WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'APL%'" );
```

However when I try this:

```
ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery("SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM USER_TABLES " +
" WHERE RDIMARS LIKE 'P_NUMBER'" );
```

as an attempt to mimic my first function code, it fails. What I would like to do is:

```
ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery("SELECT P_NUMBER from RDIMARS );
```

This does not work for me. But that exact code works in SQLplus. Any idea what I am doing wrong?  The SQLplus command I use is `select P_NUMBER from RDIMARS;`

Comment: You are missing an ending quote on `("SELECT P_NUMBER from RDIMARS )`. Is that true, or just a cut and paste error?  What is your actual error message? First statement looks okay. Second statement doesn't make sense (there is no column called `RDIMARS` in `USER_TABLES`. Third statement is missing that quote, but otherwise is okay if you have a table called `RDIMARS` with a column `P_NUMBER`.

Comment: not sure what doesnt work means please elaborate.